# In Javascript, how can you inherit and extend a method that is being inherited?

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js, prototype

I've searched around, but haven't found a duplicate of this question, unfortunately.

File1:

```
var Graph = Backbone.View.extend({
  move: function() {
    //some stuff
  }, //more stuff
})
```

File 2:

```
define ([ './graph.js' ]), function( graph ) {
  var SubGraph = Backbone.View.extend({
// this file needs to inherit what is within the move method but extend it to include other stuff
   })
```

How do you extend the inherited properties without destroying the existing ones?

Comment: Can you give more details on your expectation?

Comment: I think you can do `var SubGraph = Graph.extend(...`, in order to set up the inheritance, but I'm not sure... (I have only dealt with Backbone once in the past)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Require.js

Do:

Graph module:

```
define(function() {
  return Backbone.View.extend({
    move: function() {
    //some stuff
  }
});
```

SubGraph module:

```
define(['require', './graph'], function(require) {
  var Graph = require('./graph');

  return Graph.extend({
    // this file needs to inherit what....
  }
});
```

Or if you don't define a lot of dependencies, don't include `require`:

```
define(['./graph'], function(Graph) {
  return Graph.extend({
    // this file needs to inherit what....
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend a statement within the move method? E.G: Graph's move method contains a statement, this.model.save({}), which saves x and y coordinates, and I would like from within the move method of subgraph to extend the statement or replace it to inlcude z-coordinates; this is what the graph object currently contains: move: function(){this.model.save({x-coord: this.deltaX, y-coord: this.deltaY})

Comment: You can't extend it because it's a function not a constructor. If you used `move` as `var moveA = new move()`, you could do `move.prototype.newMethod = function()...` but looks like this is not the case.

Comment: Just to be clear, do I need to do anything to move: function() {...} within graph.js (is that technically considered a constructor function?) or just do var moveA = new move(); move: function(){//some extra functionality} within subgraph.js? Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: if you don't need to modify `move`, you will already have it when you do `Graph.extend`. Your question was re. modifying it - but if you want to modify `move` than why do you need to extent `Graph` in the first place? You normally extend because you DON'T need to modify most of the methods of the class you extend ))

Comment: move has several statements that I would like to inherit and use in subgraph and other views, it's just the 'this.model.save...' statement which needs to be changed